# Deserializing the xml document is changing the value of node in the xml

Tags: deserialization

I have an xml and i update the treeview based on the text with in the xml.
Sample xml:

```
<TaskSeverity></TaskSeverity>
<TaskCategory></TaskCategory>
<TaskTitle></TaskTitle>
<TaskMessage></TaskMessage>
<TaskCode></TaskCode>
<TaskName>SQL_MAPPING_COMPANIES</TaskName>
<Schema>CLIENT</Schema>
<!-- Schema is a required field -->
<Mapping>Companies</Mapping>
<!-- Mapping is a required field -->
<CacheDb>false</CacheDb>
<!-- CacheDb is an optional field. Default value is false -->
<DeleteTableBeforeExecute>true</DeleteTableBeforeExecute>
<!-- DeleteTableBeforeExecute is an optional field. Default value is false -->
```

Now i have a method which does that.

```
public void UpdateTreeView(XmlDocument xDoc)
      {
         xmlTreeViewAdv.Nodes.Clear();
         _nodeToTaskDictionary.Clear();
         if (xDoc == null)
            return;
         TreeNodeAdv rootNode = new TreeNodeAdv(xDoc.DocumentElement.Name);
         if (rootNode.Text.Equals("DmtTask") && xDoc.DocumentElement != null)
         {
            foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in xDoc.DocumentElement.Attributes)
            {
               if (attribute.Name.Equals("xsi:type"))
               {
                  rootNode.Text = attribute.Value;
               }
            }
         }



   xmlTreeViewAdv.Nodes.Add(rootNode);


      rootNode.Font = new Font(rootNode.Font, FontStyle.Bold);

_nodeToTaskDictionary.Add(rootNode, DmtTaskToolbox.FromXml(xDoc));
//This particular line does the deserialization part.

}
```

// where _nodeToTaskDictionary is

```
 public Dictionary<TreeNodeAdv, DmtTask> _nodeToTaskDictionary = new Dictionary<TreeNodeAdv, DmtTask>();

//where TreeNodeAdv is the Treeview (Syncfusion) and DmtTask is an abstract class

public static class DmtTaskToolbox
   {
      public static DmtTask FromXml(XmlDocument xDoc)
      {
         DmtTask t = DmtTask.DmtXmlSerializer.Deserialize(new XmlNodeReader(xDoc)) as DmtTask;
          // As soon as the above line is executed the value of the last node DeleteTableBeforeExecute innerText is changing to False. I could not understand the reason for it
         if (t == null)
            throw new Exception("Unable to convert the specific XML document DmtTask");
         return t;
      }
   }
```

public static XmlSerializer DmtXmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DmtTask), DmtTaskTypes);

Based on the value of that node i will be deleting the entire records from the table and insert new records. But its returning false.

This is what is see after the deserialization

```
<TaskSeverity></TaskSeverity>
<TaskCategory></TaskCategory>
<TaskTitle></TaskTitle>
<TaskMessage></TaskMessage>
<TaskCode></TaskCode>
<TaskName>SQL_MAPPING_COMPANIES</TaskName>
<Schema>CLIENT</Schema>
<!-- Schema is a required field -->
<Mapping>Companies</Mapping>
<!-- Mapping is a required field -->
<CacheDb>false</CacheDb>
<!-- CacheDb is an optional field. Default value is false -->
<DeleteTableBeforeExecute>false</DeleteTableBeforeExecute>
<!-- DeleteTableBeforeExecute is an optional field. Default value is false -->
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Found out the issue. The issue was with the public variable defined with in the abstract class DeleteTableBeforeExectue was different from the spelling of the tag DeleteTableBeforeExecute defined in the xmldocument which i was trying to deserialize.  When serializing classes to XML, each public property and field value is transformed into an XML element. The name of the element matches the name of the property. The XmlElement attribute allows the names and formatting of XML tags to be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the public variable defined with in the abstract class DeleteTableBeforeExectue was different from the spelling of the tag DeleteTableBeforeExecute defined in the xmldocument which i was trying to deserialize.

**When serializing classes to XML, each public property and field value is transformed into an XML element. The name of the element matches the name of the property. The XmlElement attribute allows the names and formatting of XML tags to be modified**